# How to block touches began and touches ends methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, touch

In my iPad app I have a class called cell.

When I touch the cell, order of execution of the delegate methods for touch is as follows:

1) Touches Began

2) Touches Moved

3) Touches Ended

Is there a way I can call these three methods for one cell?

I want all three methods to be called first for one cell, and then for the other cells.

**Ideally** this should happen.

```
                                                     Touches Began 13
2012-02-20 09:52:21.918 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Ended 13

2012-02-20 09:52:21.536 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Began 14
2012-02-20 09:52:21.566 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Ended 14

If it ommits the touch for cell 14 is also absolutely acceptable.
```

What is happening is missing the sequence, so getting undesirable results.

```
                                                     Touches Began 13
2012-02-20 09:52:21.536 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Began 14
2012-02-20 09:52:21.538 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Ended 13
2012-02-20 09:52:21.566 ShuffleDemoForiPad[3038:707] Touches Ended 14
```

Thanks.

Comment: confusing.... question..i'm not getting what you want...!!!

Comment: Very confusing question. Please try rewriting to allow us to better help you.

Comment: Please write your questions in a short yet understandable manner. Long descriptions with no proper meaning doesn't help.

Comment: Have you also implemented `touchesCancelled`? if not, do so, and you can set it to act as `touchesEnded` (this is the only reason I can think of, that can cause touchesEnded not to be called).

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing that you want to skip cell's user interactions for cell numbered 0,2,4,6..... So may be this can help you.

```
if (indexPath.row%2==0)
{
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
else
{
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```